# GSM/GPRS reach for Class 4 2W 900MHz/ Class 1 1W 1800Mhz

Tags: rf, communication, gsm, waveform, gprs

I'm studying differents GSM/GPRS modules and all of them have two operation modes depending the frecuency (900MHz and 1800Mhz). If I'm not wrong, for the same power higher frecuencies have a lower reach and higher trassmision rate than lower frecuencies.

My question is, how can I know the reach in meters of each range for a power of 2W or 33dBm in 900MHz and 1W or 30dBm in 1800MHz.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot write it... The question is for ideal conditions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm not wrong, for the same power higher frecuencies have a lower
>   reach

Irrespective of frequency, the power radiated from an antenna is the same (if the power input to that antenna is constant). This means that at some arbitrary distance from a transmitting antenna, the same power density is present (watts per square metre) irrespective of frequency.

However, because a receiving antenna has a size that is dependent on wavelength, the *effective area* is becomes smaller with an increase in frequency. The bottom line is that the antenna receives less power and produces a smaller signal as frequency rises.

> Sorry, I forgot write it... The question is for ideal conditions.

The formula that I use for the free-field assessment of link loss (power loss between transmit and receive antennas) is based on the Friis formula: -

Link Loss (dB) = 32.4 + 20\$log_{10}\$(F) + 20\$log_{10}\$(d)

where F is MHz and d is distance between the two antennas (kilometres).

If "F" were 2 (implying a doubling of operating frequency) the loss part of the equation would increase by 6.02 dB.

> My question is, how can I know the reach in meters of each range for a
>   power of 2W or 33dBm in 900MHz and 1W or 30dBm in 1800MHz.

To know how far you can get ideally in free-space you need to have a figure for the data rate you transmit at. If the data rate is really low you can design a receiver that has a very tight band-pass filter that excludes a lot of noise - this allows you to receive a signal that is much smaller and therefore distance can increase. Anyway the rule of thumb equation is this: -

Power required by receive antenna in dBm is -154dBm + 10\$log_{10}\$(data rate) dBm

So now you have an estimate of the power you need at the receiver based on data rate, a formula that describes how power is attenuated in free-space (link-loss) and you have your output power (1 or 2 watts). All you need to do is combine this lot together to get an estimate. On the good side, the gain (dBi) of the sending and receiving antennas makes the link-loss smaller. On the down side, operating conditions can vastly increase the link-loss both statically and dynamically. In fact this is a big subject and has spawned several different mathematical models by cellular handset companies and other interested parties.

The most basic form this takes is to say that link-loss will be at least 20 dB worse than the free-space model - the 20 dB factor is called Fade margin. There is also another commonly used models for link loss [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hata_model_for_open_areas). This is the Hata model for open areas: -

[image]

where

- LO = Path loss in open area. Unit: decibel (dB)
- LU = Path loss in urban areas for small sized city. Unit: decibel (dB)
- f = Frequency of transmission. Unit: Megahertz (MHz).

There is also the [**Okumura model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okumura_model) for urban areas: -

[image]

where,

L = The median path loss. Unit: Decibel (dB)

LFSL = The free space loss. Unit: decibel (dB)

AMU = Median attenuation. Unit: decibel (dB)

HMG = Mobile station antenna height gain factor.

HBG = Base station antenna height gain factor.

Kcorrection = Correction factor gain (such as type of environment, water surfaces, isolated obstacle etc.)

You also might be interested in [**this**](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/wireless-range/) website for estimating range. There is also [**this**](http://www.random-science-tools.com/electronics/friis.htm) calculator.